# Proving two sides of a convex quadrilateral are equal for given condition.

Tags: geometry, quadrilateral

> The length of each side of a convex quadrilateral ABCD is a positive integer. If the sum of
> the lengths of any three sides is divisible by the length of the remaining side then prove that
> some two sides of the quadrilateral have the same length.

**Attempt:**

I could not understand what to do, so I looked at the solution. The proposed solution is:

[image]

I do not understand 'Here $l, m, n$ are necessarily distinct. Suppose $l = m$'

I did not understand why they say that they are distinct and assume that they are equal. Yes, it might be a proof by contradiction but we already have assumed one thing above: considering all the sides of quadrilateral are distinct.

Rather, I would like to know the approach to this problem than the solution itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To spell out the part that you don't understand:

> Here, we will show that $l, m, n$ are distinct. Suppose not, WLOG say $l=m$, then we get a contradiction since $la = mb \Rightarrow a = b$. Hence, $l \neq m$.

Comment: I clearly misunderstood the statement. Thankyou!